# Setting Yesterday to Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am trying to set yesterdays day to a `Jquery` `datapicker` as follows:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", (new Date().getDate() - 1) );
```

However, I am always getting todays date. The code is located in `$(document).ready` and it does get excuted, cause if I comment out the line abobve, no value shows up.

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", -1)`
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: @mishik does what I want, please add as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", -1)
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aliyob/1)

Comment: $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", "-1")

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: -1 });
```

That ought to do the trick, courtesy of http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-defaultDate

Answer (score 1):

It's worked for me ...

```
$(".datepicker")..datepicker("setDate", "-1d");
```

link [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)