# jQuery Datepicker setDate to out of range does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

jQuery datepicker widget.

If you try to set the date to a date that is BEFORE the `minDate` option, it will default to today.

```
var yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));
$("#dateSelector").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth:true
})
.datepicker('setDate', yesterday );
```

This is super annoying and means that you cannot prepopulate a field if it should have a value that is out of date.

Anybody managed to find a way around this?

Using jQuery UI 1.8 and jquery 1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DatePicker -- Changing minDate and maxDate on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267903/jquery-datepicker-changing-mindate-and-maxdate-on-the-fly)

Comment: Not the same problem. Mine is doing it once, not based off other datepickers, and doesn't need a dynamic range that changes. It simply sets the val to be an out of date value that then gets overriden by jQuery.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990260/setting-yesterday-to-jquery-datepicker)

Comment: Closer, but mine is in a seperate input box which is displayed to the user, not the straight calendar.